# Existence for a nonlinear evolution equation with a monotone operator that is not maximal

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, banach-spaces, semigroups-of-operators

We consider the nonlinear evolution equation
$$
  \dot{u}(t) + Bu(t) = 0, \quad u(0)=0  
$$
with
$$
   A: \mathcal{C}(\Omega)\to \mathcal{M}(\Omega),\; p \mapsto \arg\min_{\mu\in\partial\chi_{\{||\cdot||_{\infty}\leq 1\}}(p)}||L^\ast\mu-f||^2_{L^2(\mathcal{X},\rho)} \\
   B: L^2(\mathcal{X},\rho)\to L^2(\mathcal{X},\rho),\; u \mapsto L^\ast A(Lu)-f
$$
where $L: L^2(\mathcal{X},\rho)\to \mathcal{C}(\Omega)$ is a bounded linear operator, $L^\ast$ its adjoint, $f\in L^2(\mathcal{X},\rho)$, $\rho$ a probablity measure over $\mathcal{X}$, and $\partial\chi_{\{||\cdot||_{\infty}\leq 1\}}$ the subgradient of the closed unit ball of continuous functions.

> Does a solution $u$ exist to the evolution equation?

Normally, a solution would exist by e.g. the procedure in [Nonlinear semigroups and evolution equations](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1260478322) by Kato. Since $A(Lu)\in \partial\chi_{\{||\cdot||_{\infty}\leq 1\}}(Lu)$, it is monotone. However, $B$ is not a maximally monotone operator. Hence, the construction of a solution using the map $J_n=(1+n^{-1}B)^{-1}$ no longer works, in particular the step "$u+Au=y$ has a solution $u$ for all $y\in L^2(\mathcal{X},\rho)$" no longer holds. One difference between the normal situation and ours, is that we don't consider an arbitrary initial condition $u(0)\in L^2(\mathcal{X},\rho)$ but $u(0)=0$.

How would we show that a solution still exists? Any recommended resources that could help to solve this problem?

Comment: Why is B not maximal? Isn't it a subgradient as well? For this you would need some kind of "constraint qualification" to make the chain rule for subgradient to hold.

Comment: The reasoning for this uses "An monotone operator $A$ is maximal if and only if $graph(A)\subseteq graph(S) => A=S$ for all monotone operators $S$". In our case, $graph(A)\subseteq graph(\partial\chi_{\{||\cdot||\leq 1\}})$ and $A\neq \partial\chi_{\{||\cdot||\leq 1\}}$. $L$ and $L^\ast$ are bounded and linear, so $B$ shouldn't be maximal. Or is this conclusion incorrect?

Comment: Ah, I misread the definition of A.